# Stripe: charge full amount to Customer even if CancelAt field is set

Tags: stripe-payments

Here's the use case I am trying to solve for:

Create a new monthly subscription of $1000 that starts on May 20 with the CancelAt field set to June 29.

Expected behavior:

1. Stripe charges Customer $1000 on May 20
2. Stripe charges Customer $1000 on June 20
3. Stripe automatically cancels the subscription on June 29 with no further invoices
4. Total amount charged: $2000

What I tried:

1. Create a Susbcription with CancelAt of June 20 and ProrateBehavior=None

Actual Stripe behaviour:

1. Stripe charged Customer $1000 on May 20 (correct)
2. I see in the Stripe dashboard an upcoming invoice of $317.97 for period June 21 - June 29 (incorrect)
3. I see in the Stripe dashboard that Subscription is set to cancel on June 29 (correct)
4. Total amount that will be charged: $1317.97 (incorrect)

I can't seem to figure out what combination of fields would make stripe behave as I described. Isn't setting the Prorate behavior to None supposed to tell Stripe to never charge less than full amount? Seems like a common use case unless I am missing something?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Stripe Subscriptions are prepaid, so your May 20 invoice actually covers from May 20 to June 20, so this actually makes sense.

[cancel_at specifically says](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-cancel_at):

> A timestamp at which the subscription should cancel. If set to a date
>   before the current period ends, this will cause a proration if
>   prorations have been enabled using proration_behavior. **If set during a
>   future period, this will always cause a proration for that period.** (emphasis mine)

You either want to just cancel the Subscription *in June* via the API with `proration_behavior:none` - potentially using metadata to record the 'when to cancel date' and webhooks to check if the subscription needs cancelling this period - or possibly use Subscription Schedules: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right the doc states the behaviour I am seeing. I would like to avoid canceling the subscription in a webhook, how would using a Subscription Schedule help?

Comment: You would build a schedule with the right number of iterations, and then set `end_behavior` to `cancel`: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules#completing-schedule